# Subtables on top of each other

Tags: subfloats

I want the subtables to be placed vertically, i.e the one above the other at the center of the page. The following code is what I have, but the output is two horizontally aligned subtables.

```latex
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Test1}
    \begin{subtable}[t]{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtable 1}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Col 1} & Col 2 \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Cell 1} & 1 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \begin{subtable}[t]{.3\linewidth}
        \caption{Subtable 2}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Col 1} & Col 2 \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Cell 1} & 1 \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Cell 2} & 2 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try adding a blank line between the subtables.

Comment: Adding a blank line using `\\`  between the subtables does not work for me.